# Is it possible to create a function to increment or decrease a variable by one, without looping or recursion(wxpython)

Tags: python, wxpython

I have logical problem in my script.
This script is supposed to create two buttons namely, add_button and subtract_button. When the add button is clicked it will increment a variable by one and if it was clicked again it should add 1 to the variable bringing the value to two. Also when the subtract button is clicked it should subtract 1 from the variable. Now that the variable is 2 when the subtract button is clicked the resultant value should be 1 and when clicked again it should become zero.
How do I achieve this WITHOUT using loop and recursion? I have tried and tried without success..

```
class ButtonBasic(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ButtonBasic, self).__init__(parent)
        self.frame = wx.Panel(self)
        self.index=0
        self.next_list=[]
        self.previous_list = []
        self.but_next = wx.Button(self.frame, label="Next")
        self.but_prev = wx.Button(self.frame, label="Previous")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: self.next(self.index, self.next_list), self.but_next)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: self.prev(self.index, self.next_list), self.but_prev)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.but_next)
        self.sizer.Add(self.but_prev)
        self.frame.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.frame.Layout()
    def next(self, idx, next_list):
        idx+=1
        if len(next_list)==1:
            next_list[0]=idx + next_list[0]
            idx=next_list[0]
            print(idx)
        else:
            next_list.append(idx)
            idx = next_list[0]
            print(idx)
    def prev(self, idx, next_list):
        idx-=1
        if len(next_list)==1:
            print(f"before substracting: {idx}")
            next_list[0]=idx - next_list[0]
            print(f"After substracting: {idx}")
            idx=next_list[0]
            print(idx)
        else:
            next_list.append(idx)
            idx = next_list[0]
            print(idx)
            
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = ButtonBasic(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way, is to forget `lambda` functions and use specific `instance` variables for specific buttons, `not` local variables, after all you are declaring specific functions for each button event i.e.:

```
import wx

class ButtonBasic(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ButtonBasic, self).__init__(parent)
        self.frame = wx.Panel(self)
        self.next_index = 0
        self.previous_index = 0
        self.next_list=[]
        self.previous_list = []
        self.but_next = wx.Button(self.frame, label="Next")
        self.but_prev = wx.Button(self.frame, label="Previous")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.next, self.but_next)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.prev, self.but_prev)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.but_next)
        self.sizer.Add(self.but_prev)
        self.frame.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.frame.Layout()

    def next(self, event):
        self.next_index += 1
        self.next_list.append(self.next_index)
        print(self.next_index)

    def prev(self, event):
        self.previous_index -= 1
        self.previous_list.append(self.previous_index)
        print(self.previous_index)

    def OnClose(self, event):
        print("Next History:", self.next_list)
        print("Previous History:", self.previous_list)
        self.Destroy()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = ButtonBasic(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

However, as your code and description don't quite match, you may want a single variable shared between the two buttons.
In which case the code could need to be like this:

```
import wx

class ButtonBasic(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ButtonBasic, self).__init__(parent)
        self.frame = wx.Panel(self)
        self.index = 0
        self.next_list=[]
        self.previous_list = []
        self.but_next = wx.Button(self.frame, label="Next")
        self.but_prev = wx.Button(self.frame, label="Previous")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.next, self.but_next)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.prev, self.but_prev)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.but_next)
        self.sizer.Add(self.but_prev)
        self.frame.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.frame.Layout()

    def next(self, event):
        self.index += 1
        self.next_list.append(self.index)
        print(self.index)

    def prev(self, event):
        self.index -= 1
        self.previous_list.append(self.index)
        print(self.index)

    def OnClose(self, event):
        print("Next History:", self.next_list)
        print("Previous History:", self.previous_list)
        self.Destroy()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = ButtonBasic(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: The first code I posted was the wrong code. It was the first draft but I have edited the post to reflect the right code. I am sorry for the inconvinience please. My proble is whenever I clicked the substarct button it is nt working as expected. When I clic it when the result is = 3 it will output -4 and when I clicked the button again the answer will return to 3. If clicked again it will give -4 back and again it will give us 3.

Comment: Your last code works. However the first one you posted does not. When you clicked the substract button it count backwards. -1 to -n times you clicked the substract button. Perhaps, it is because of the fact you declare two index as the variables. Variable self.next_index and self,previous_index. I feel whenever you clicked the substract button it is only the self.previous_index that get updated. So, I will try and adapt your scrit to what I have in mind and see.

Comment: Thanks so very much to you. I got to understand that I don't need the list., as why I think I need the list is because I need to store the index and get it whenever I am processing the addition and substraction in both functions. Let me do away with the both list and test the code.

Comment: @Z.Edibo The reason there are 2 pieces of code, is that the code originally posted and the description, seemed at odds with each other, so I posted two slightly different answers for you to choose from, depending on what you really intended. Glad it helped, eventually. :)